Kubernetes and Traefik creating an appropriate Ingress resource for an application
I am running a kubernetes cluster and have a TestApplication that runs on TestPort (3000 actually). I managed to get Traefik v3.2.1 up and running and CertManager 1.16.1 with http challenge to letsencrypt up and running. I would like to protect the TestApplication making people pass trough TraefiK port 443 and land into TestApplication:TestPort.
How do I create an appropriate Ingress resource for my application?
so far I did:
 #001-app-deployment.yml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app-frontend
  name: app-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: app-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: app-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: API_GATEWAY_BASE_URL
              value: http://edge-thinghy:9000
          image: my-image-I-test
          name: app-frontend
          ports:
            -  name: app-frontend
               containerPort: 3000
               protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ghcr-secret
      restartPolicy: Always

#010-app-service.yml
        apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: app-frontend
    
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: app-frontend
          port: 80
          targetPort: 3000
    
      selector:
        app: app-frontend
    
    #011-app-ingress.yml
    
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: app-ingress
    spec:
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-frontend
                port: 
                  name: app-frontend
    
    #012-challenge.yml

    apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
    kind: Issuer
    metadata:
     name: app-challenge
     namespace: default
    spec:
     acme:
       email: my.mail@my.domain
       server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
       privateKeySecretRef:
          name: app-issuer-account-key
       solvers:
         - http01:
             ingress:
               class: traefik
    
    #013-ingress-rule.yml
    
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
     name: app-ssl-ingress
     namespace: default
     annotations:
       cert-manager.io/issuer: "app-challenge"
    spec:
     tls:
       - hosts:
           - app.domain.example
         secretName: tls-app-ingress-http
     rules:
       - host: app.domain.example
         http:
           paths:
             - path: /
               pathType: Prefix
               backend:
                 service:
                   name: app-frontend
                   port:
                     name: app-frontend

Since the certificates are issued I was expecting Traefik to automatically work but I get timeouted when I go to https://app.domain.example. I think I'm doing something wrong. If I open traefik pod logs I can see:
    ERR Skipping service: no endpoints found ingress=app-ingress namespace=default providerName=kubernetes serviceName=app-frontend servicePort=&ServiceBackendPort{Name:app-frontend,Number:0,}
    ERR Skipping service: no endpoints found ingress=app-ssl-ingress namespace=default providerName=kubernetes serviceName=app-frontend servicePort=&ServiceBackendPort{Name:app-frontend,Number:0,}

I can although get to http://app.domain.example not to https
if I do
    kubectl get ingress
NAME               CLASS     HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS 
app-ingress       traefik   *                            80     
app-ssl-ingress   traefik   app.domain.example           80, 443


The getting started documentation includes example ingress manifests.

@larsks I think I did the ingress manifest. 013-ingress-rule.yml 011-app-ingress.yml am I misunderstanding something? thank you for your time

look like you forget the deployment manifest
here the example :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-frontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3  # Adjust the desired number of replicas
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-frontend
        image: your-image-name:your-image-tag  # Replace with your image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000


thank you for your time, oh sorry, of course I have a deployment I try to edit the question and see if it fits.

Something miss in your deployment and service
Your Deployment uses the following label:
io.kompose.service: app-frontend
But your Service selector is:
app: app-frontend
This mismatch prevents the service from finding the pods created by the deployment. Fix the Service selector to match the Deployment label:
Update 010-app-service.yml:
spec:
selector:
io.kompose.service: app-frontend

thank you, the error changed but I feel you explained very well what my issue was. The story of my experiment with kubernetes will continue here: https://community.traefik.io/t/have-i-understood-correctly-how-to-protect-a-program-in-kubernetes-with-traefik/
